# Are you able to use the Nintendo Switch pro controller when the console is undocked?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch

I would like to know if you are still able to use the Switch's pro controller even when the console is undocked? Also, how many controllers can be connected to the Switch, docked and undocked (or is there no difference)?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12272/tag-synonyms-nintendo-switch)

Comment: So what you guys are saying is that it will work.lol

Comment: Please stop using the comments here to discuss the tag - we have a meta post for it. Discuss it there, and refrain from any edit wars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

> The Pro Controller can be used whether the Switch is docked or undocked and regardless of Mode. It can be used either when the Nintendo Switch is docked at home and connected to a television in TV Mode or when the Nintendo Switch screen is undocked in Tabletop Mode, allowing the screen to become a portable television screen for the Pro Controller to be used with.

<sub>[(Source)](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/nintendo-switch/Nintendo_Switch_Pro_Controller)</sub>